# Shell script substring from first indexof substring

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I want to accomplish the equivalent of the following pseudo-code in bash (both a and b are inputs to my script) :

```
String a = "some long string";
String b = "ri";
print (a.substring(a.firstIndexOf(b), a.length()); //prints 'ring'
```

How can I do this in shell script?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do:

```
$ a="some long string"
$ b="ri"
$ echo $a | grep -o "$b.*"
ring
```

Comment: not index of but the string itself and pops error if not find

Answer (score 20):

Try:

```
    $ a="some long string"
    $ b="ri"

    $ echo ${a/*$b/$b}
    ring

    $ echo ${a/$b*/$b}
    some long stri
```

Comment: Clever. You should double-quote the argument to `echo`, though.

Comment: This is a greedy match, so if there is a second "ri", this prints until and from the second match, not the first.

Answer (score 3):

`grep`, `sed` and so on can be used but it is not pure-bash.

`expr` is a good choice but `index` parameter is not, because it matches character not the whole string, try with `a = "some wrong string"` it matches the first `r`.

Instead use `expr match` with its regular expression parameter :

```
a="some long string";
b="ri";
echo ${a:$(expr match "$a" ".*${b}") - $(expr length "$b")}
```

It also works with `a = "some wrong string"`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a="some long string"
b="ri"

echo  ${b}${a#*${b}}
```